# I face this export error of Cookie using in react

Tags: reactjs, cookies

I do have this code and I'm going to use Cookies for first time but I get error below , anyone who can help me to fix the problem ?

"ERROR I FACE : Attempted import error: 'react-cookie' does not contain a default export (imported as 'Cookie').  "

```
import React from 'react';    
import ReactDom from 'react-dom';    
import './App.css';    
import CountDown from './CountDown';
import Basket from './Basket';    


import Cookie from 'react-cookie'
class Products extends React.Component{    

constructor(props){
    super(props);
   this.state={
       order : []  
   } 
 this.shop = this.shop.bind(this);
}  
   prevstate = [];
   `enter code here`shop(evt){

this.prevstate.push(evt.target.id);
this.setState({
    order : this.prevstate
})
console.log(Cookie.get('selected'))
Cookie.set('selected' , this.props.cart , {path :' /'});

   }

render(){
    return(
        <div className="prowrap">

         {this.props.prolist.map((name) => (
         <div  className="pro" key={name.id} style={{border:"1px red 
solid"}} >
         <img src={name.image}/>
         <p>{name.name}</p>
         <p>{name.detail}</p>  
         <p className="countdown"><CountDown time={name.date}/></p>
         <div className="price">{name.price} Euro</div>
         <button className="shop" id={name.id} onClick={this.shop}>Add To 
Cart</button>    
         </div>))}
        <Basket cart={this.state.order} allpro={this.props.prolist}/>
        </div>
    )
}
}

export default Products;
```

Comment: Read the package notes on how to use it at https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie/#readme

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear react-cookie doesn’t have default export so you cannot import it like

```
   import Cookie from 'react-cookie';
```

You need to import it like below

```
  import { Cookies } from 'react-cookie';
```

Also it's not Cookie but Cookies. You are importing it wrongly

When it is default export then you don’t use {} to import but if it is not default export then you use {} to import it.

Comment: thanks for your answer I'm so new with react , I did as you said but get same error Attempted import error: 'Cookie' is not exported from 'react-cookie'.

Comment: @Bita Its Cookies but not Cookie. Please check my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to import like `import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';` and then `cookies.get('selected')`, refer the code below

**Read the [package readme](https://github.com/reactivestack/cookies/tree/master/packages/react-cookie/#readme) carefully.**

```
// App.jsx
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { instanceOf } from 'prop-types';
import { withCookies, Cookies } from 'react-cookie';

import NameForm from './NameForm';

class App extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    cookies: instanceOf(Cookies).isRequired
  };

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const { cookies } = props;
    this.state = {
      name: cookies.get('name') || 'Ben'
    };
  }

  handleNameChange(name) {
    const { cookies } = this.props;

    cookies.set('name', name, { path: '/' });
    this.setState({ name });
  }

  render() {
    const { name } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <NameForm name={name} onChange={this.handleNameChange.bind(this)} />
        {this.state.name && <h1>Hello {this.state.name}!</h1>}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default withCookies(App);
```